# Is it possible to use FROM in PS query expression? If not is there an alternative solution?

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm new with PS Query and SQL. I have a working SQL however I cannot translate it to PS Query.

So basically, I would like to present the comparison of my products and its amount per column.

Here are my sample data:

```
Product | Month | Amount
--------|-------|-------
Phone   | 2     | 25 
Laptop  | 2     | 30 
Phone   | 1     | 20 
Laptop  | 1     | 40
```

Below is the code that I'm having hard time translating to PS Query:

```
Select ….
  SUM(CASE WHEN Product1 <> Product2 AND Product2 = Laptop THEN 30
/*On my second statement, when the product are equal, i need to get the amount on the previous month.*/
           WHEN Product1 = Product3 AND Product3 = Phone 
           THEN (SELECT Amount
                  FROM FINAL_TBL B
                  WHERE B.PERIOD = A.PERIOD - 1)
              ELSE 0
       END) AS Amount

From FINAL_TBL FTBL A
Where <Conditions>
```

My expected output should be

```
Product1    | Amount1   | Product2  | Amount2   | Product3  | Amount3
------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------
Phone       | 25        | Laptop    | 30        | Phone     | 20
```

Comment: Could you format your sample data and expected results in row/column form, as well as denote which fields are the primary key(s)?  I'm confused by what your data looks like, and what you're trying to accomplish with your query.  It looks like you're trying to put a bunch of table rows into a single row in your query.  Is that correct?  If so, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: The primary key is the Product. My requirement is to compare 4 products and its amounts in a column format for easier comparison. Because in the future we are expecting that the number of the products will increase.

Comment: If you're planning on increasing the number of products, then I recommend against trying to put all products on the same row.  As far as I know, PeopleSoft doesn't let you have a dynamic number of columns, so you'll constantly have to update your query as you add more products.  I think a better design would to have each row in your result be just a single product and its amount, joined with its amount from month X - 1.  The blueprint that I have in my answer below could be used to do that.

Comment: If you want everything to be on a single row, you could do it as an SQR report.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I'm thinking is use a prompts for the product to be more dynamic. Do you think will that be feasible?

But when I'm trying that, I'm still struggling when getting the prior month since the subquery is not possible in the Select statement on PS Query.

Comment: The subquery is possible if you use my answer below to make a view with the subquery in it.  However, I still think you're going to struggle with having to continuously add PRODUCT and AMOUNT fields to your query results as you add more types of products.  I'd recommend either redesign how you want to do your query, or write an SQR report if you want to have this sort of more complicated logic where you're joining each row to its prior month and have a dynamic number of products.

Comment: Adding a limited number of prompts as you suggest would solve the problem of having a dynamic number of columns in the result if you only select products for which the user select that product in one of the prompts.  It'll still be a messy query though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `FROM` in a PSQUERY expression.

The query you are trying to translate can be rewritten to:

```
Select *
  SUM(CASE WHEN Product1 <> Product2 AND Product2 = Laptop 
                THEN 30
           WHEN Product1 = Product3 AND Product3 = Phone 
                THEN B.Amount
           ELSE 0
       END) AS Amount
FROM FINAL_TBL A, FINAL_TBL B
WHERE B.PERIOD = A.PERIOD - 1
AND <Conditions>
```

But neither this or the original query would lead to the output you expect. What you are looking for is the [PIVOT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) clause.

Comment: Thanks for update. Is it possible that my report will be dynamic with PIVOT clause? In the future, we are expecting that products will increase and change.

Comment: @IvanChristopherSenica No, pivot requires you to specify the column names beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into a situation where I have a complicated query that's difficult or impossible to build through PSQuery, I make a view in App Designer that has the SQL.

[image]

[image]

Then make a PSQuery where you select from this view.  I assume your `<conditions>` are user-entered data that you want to be entered when running the query, so add those conditions to the PSQuery that you build.

**However**, I think you should rethink what you're trying to do with your query.  It looks like you're trying to list all products/prices that were bought in month X, as well as the price for the first product for month X - 1.  With just two possible products (laptops and phones), this'll work, but when you start adding more types of products, you'll need more `PRODUCT` and `PRICE` columns.  I don't think you'll be able to do that through PSQuery because you can't have a dynamic number of columns.

If you could explain what you're trying to accomplish and why, then someone might be able to suggest an alternative that'll work through PSQuery.